# iTextSharp Signature Image not showing in PDF Signature Field

Tags: itext

I have researched this issue for most of the day.  I have an existing application that uses iTextSharp to sign PDF documents.  The digital signature exists and the text representation shows within the Signature Field on the PDF but the Image of the signature does not show.

The following is the code in question.  I appreciate any help/advice you can offer.

```
if (signatureBitmap != null)
{
    if (reader == null) reader = new PdfReader(PDFByteArray);

    pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, outputStream, PDFVersion, null, true);

    PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

    //Add digital certificate to field
    signatureAppearance.SetCrypto(Key, Certificate, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);
    signatureAppearance.Reason = Reason;
    signatureAppearance.Location = Location;

    signatureAppearance.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.GraphicAndDescription;

    if (signatureBitmap != null)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image signatureFieldImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(signatureBitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        signatureAppearance.SignatureGraphic = signatureFieldImage;
    }

    signatureAppearance.Acro6Layers = acroLayer;
    signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(acrobatSignatureFieldName);
    pdfStamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
    reader = null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the position about your signature, try with this:

```
Rectangle rSignature= new Rectangle(100,100);
signatureAppearance.setVisibleSignature(rSignature, 1, "a name");
```